# UWP MapControl get XAML childrens by offset

Tags: uwp, uwp-maps

Is there a away to get XAML children with offset or Geolocation?
Like the builtin function of the MapControl

```
MapControl.FindMapElementsAtOffset(Point p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the map control doesn't know the extent of the XAML element, it can't hit test them. XAML elements are only pinned to the map at a single point which is all the map control knows about.
You could try VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_VisualTreeHelper_FindElementsInHostCoordinates_Windows_Foundation_Point_Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_

Comment: thanks , this isn't working , the result is always null no matter in which sub tree you will try